# How to organise classes, packages

Tags: java, package

How do you decide what a package name should be and what class should go into what package ?

I'm working on a project where I am constantly adding/removing classes and not really sure if I need a new package, or should add it to an existing one that im not currently aware of.

Do you follow a set of rules when creating a new package ?

How do you know if you are not duplicating package functionality ? Is this just down to familiarity with the project.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: @Alex K: I don't think it's duplicated. The question you point is about how packages work in Java while this question is about how to define packages more effectively.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Classes should do one thing ([Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Classes that do related things should go in the same package. If you find you can more closely relate some of the classes in a package, make them a subpackage!

For example, if I had a project with these classes:

- `GreetingInputWindow`
- `GreetingDatabaseObject`
- `GreetingDatabaseConnector`

I might just put them all in the `greeting` package. If I wanted to, I might put `GreetingInputWindow` in the `greeting.ui` package, and the other 2 into the `greeting.db` package.

Answer (score 15):

I strongly discourage from organizing packages from an implementational point of view, like `controllers`, `data`, etc. I prefer grouping them by functionality, that is, `feature1`, `feature2`, etc. If a feature is reasonably complex and requires a large number of classes, then (and only then) I create subpackages like above, that is, `feature1.controllers`, `feature1.data`, etc.

Comment: The benefit of the approach michael667 is describing, IMO, is that it makes logging configuration much easier. If I want to see everything related to automobiles I can just configure logging in the automobile package, for example

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there are any hard and fast rules on packaging convention (though I could be wrong). Normally I break it up into

com.mycompanyname and then:

- api
- controllers
- data (for models)
- jobs (for cron jobs)
- reporting
- servlet
- utils

If I find I have a class which does not fit into any of those, then I create a new package.

Comment: Yeah, I use something similar. I find this keeps the code organised but some seem to think this isn't very good practice.